# Custom validation attribute not firing IsValid method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently implementing some custom attributes in ASP.NET Core MVC and I'm having a problem with `ValidationAttribute`. Validation should be triggered on form submit.

```C#
public class Company
{
    [CustomRequired]
    [CustomValidation]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This attribute works just fine and override is triggered in debug mode when I submit form.

```C#
public class CustomRequired : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        //logic
        return name;
    }
}
```

This one is the problem. If I make constructor it is called but overridden methods never trigger.

```C#
public class CustomValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //logic
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Also this is frontend implementation:

```Razor
@model Company;

<form method="post" asp-controller="Company" asp-action="SaveData">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, null, new {@class="text-danger"})
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I tried using some default attributes like `[Required]`, `[StringLength]` and they are all working fine and message is displayed when I click <kbd>Submit</kbd>.

Comment: Sidenote Please name the class with attribute in it so CustomRequired should be CustomRequiredAttribute. And those classes should have itself a AttributeUsageAttribute applied that they don't have as shown.

Comment: What happens if you override the standard IsValid also? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.isvalid?view=net-8.0#system-componentmodel-dataannotations-validationattribute-isvalid(system-object) The remarks for that method say "If you inherit from the ValidationAttribute class, you must implement the validation logic in this method."

Comment: @SkriTex: Can you show code of the `SaveData()`  action method? Seems like you don't initiate the binding process.

Comment: @Ralf I added standard IsValid but nothing happened. So I tried to add my attribute on Login.Email in Login.cshtml.cs from template you get when you create app and it worked. Can't figure out what is different so it works.

Comment: @Jackdaw just some data manipulation and EF. Am I missing something? Do I need to have binding code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post above doesn't contain the `SaveData()` action method definition code.

But except fixing the [custom attribute naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-attributes) (declaring `CustomValidationAttribute`) your `SaveData` action method should be declared as following:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveData(Company company)
```

If your action method isn't referencing to the `Company` object the  `IsValid()` method of the custom attribute will not be triggered.

Comment: Only thing I did wrong I was referencing IFormCollection instead of Company. Works now. Thanks!